# CodingBat Python make_chocolate code failing in "other tests"

Tags: python

There is a coding problem on CodingBat.com (Logic-2 Python section) that asks for a function to determine how many small chocolate bars are used for a weight requirement. The question is as follows:

We want make a package of goal kilos of chocolate. We have small bars (1 kilo each) and big bars (5 kilos each). Return the number of small bars to use, assuming we always use big bars before small bars. Return -1 if it can't be done.

make_chocolate(4, 1, 9) → 4
make_chocolate(4, 1, 10) → -1
make_chocolate(4, 1, 7) → 2

I came up with this solution to the problem but it still fails in "other tests". Is there any problem that causes this?

Code:

```
def make_chocolate(small, big, goal):
    if (small + 5*big < goal) or (goal % 5 > small):
        return -1

    elif small >= goal:
        return small
    else:
        smallnum = 0
        for i in range(1,big+1):
            if 5*i + small >= goal:
                if 5*i > goal:
                    break
                smallnum = goal - 5*i
        return smallnum
```

EDIT:
I have managed to finish the problem thanks to Mariah Akinbi. I have updated the code as follows:

```
def make_chocolate(small, big, goal):
    if (small + 5*big < goal) or (goal % 5 > small):
        return -1

    elif 5 <= goal:
        smallnum = 0
        for i in range(1,big+1):
            if 5*i + small >= goal:
                if 5*i > goal:
                    break
                smallnum = goal - 5*i
        return smallnum
  return goal
```

Comment: Your description of the problem is insufficient. Please explain what the task is and what "*it fails*" actually means in this context. If it is some sort of homework you might want to give a description of the task.

Comment: Your question is not clear. Just what exactly is "the problem" for which you are finding a solution? Is the failure of the code in some automated testing so you cannot tell us the input that shows the failure? And so on. Please clarify.

Comment: It's a little hard to understand what the purpose of `make_chocolate` is. Can you post the test cases and expected outputs? Include the test cases where it fails.

Comment: @StefanFalk  I updated the description

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code seems to fail on:

`make_chocolate(8,1,7)`--> returns 8 instead of 2

I believe the issue is:

```
elif small >= goal:
    return small
```

The instructions say to use the big bars first, then use the nuggets to meet the goal.

Comment: Thank for spotting that. I removed the elif portion and modified the last else and added a new return statement at the end.

Answer (score 0):

Here is much simpler solution:

```
def make_chocolate(small, big, goal):
  big_use = min(goal / 5, big)
  small_needed = goal - big_use * 5
  if small < small_needed:
    return -1
  return small_needed
```

Answer (score 0):

see my code below

```
def make_chocolate(small, big, goal):
    if goal-big*5<=small:  #find out if the total chocolate can make the goal
      if goal%5==0 and goal-big*5==0: # if small bars not required
        return 0
      if goal-big*5>0: 
        return goal-big*5
      if goal-big*5<0 and goal%5<=small:
        return goal%5
      else:
        return -1
      
    if goal-big*5>small:
      return -1
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

**A Simpler Approach**

```
def make_chocolate(smallBars, bigBars, goal):

    bigBarsInKilo =  bigBars * 5

    while bigBarsInKilo > goal:
        bigBarsInKilo -= 5

    smallBarsRequired = goal - bigBarsInKilo

    if smallBars >= abs(smallBarsRequired): # abs (to ignore negative values)
        return smallBarsRequired
    else:
        return -1

print(make_chocolate(1, 2, 5))
```

Answer (score -1):

```
def make_chocolate(small, big, goal):
  if goal> big*5 +small or goal % 5 > small:
    return -1
  elif big *5 > goal:
    return goal % 5
  else:
    return goal - big *5
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.